# How can i iteratively apply elements from the 2 lists into a new function?

Tags: python, list, iteration, user-defined-functions

Suppose I have 2 lists, for which the i-th element of the first lists corresponds to the i-th element of the second list. How can i iteratively apply elements from the 2 lists into a different function?

```
def GetLists(n):
    List1 = []
    List2 = []
    n = int(input("how many terms: "))
    for i in range(1,n):
        val1 = float(input("what is val1: "))
        val2 = float(input("what is the corresponding val2: "))
        List1.append(val1)
        List2.append(val2)
    return List1, List2

def newfunc(ListA, ListB, var):
    # take i-th elements from lists A and B where (a,b) are the i-th elements of A and B
    # want output = sum(a * var ** b) for index in len(A) if len(A) == len(B)
```

What is the most pythonic way to do this? If possible, I would like to do so without importing external modules.

Edit: I checked other solutions. The "duplicate" answer requires importing modules; I was trying to do without. Also, I am trying to do an operation that returns an output rather than print values, which complicates the use of zip beyond the level shown in the duplicate answer.

Comment: Are you looking for `for a, b in zip(ListA, ListB):`? Also, note that what you've posted isn't Python - case matters.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Which part isn't python (which part is case-dependent)? Please excuse my ignorance, I am still a beginner.

Comment: `Def` -> `def`, `For` -> `for`. If you're new, **read a tutorial**. And this is a duplicate, `zip` doesn't require an import and you can do whatever you want with `a` and `b` once you have them.

Comment: Ahhh, my careless mistake. I was typing on a mobile phone. I will edit it now.

Comment: As for being a duplicate, the "original" requires importing itertools. It also prints and does not do an operation on the zipped elements.

Comment: 1. No it doesn't, it shows an *option* that uses `itertools`. 2. So what? SO isn't a code-writing service, you are expected to be able to adapt generic answers to your specific needs.

Comment: Well, I specifically asked for an answer that does not import modules to do this. I could not adapt the methods in the "original" to my problem because I am not trying to just print my result. I don't treat SO as a code-writing service. If you feel so inclined, go to my profile and check out my other 2 most recent posts here to see how many ways I tried to this.

Comment: **The duplicate does not require you to import modules.** `zip` is built-in. Again, it simply shows *options*, alternative approaches, that do use imports (and only from the standard library, which you should *already have available*) and explains under what circumstances you'd use them. I see no point discussing this further.

Comment: Then I guess we both feel that way. Perhaps we should explore that; it's not clear to me what you do not understand. You keep saying it's not a duplicate because you don't want to import any modules. 1. Why don't you want to import any modules? Are you aware there's a difference between third-party modules and the standard library? What constraints are you operating under? That would be useful context to [edit] in. 2. Even so, as I keep saying, the duplicate doesn't *require* any imports. Why do you think it does? The answer you've actually accepted **uses `zip`, as the duplicate does**.

Comment: I feel that the best way to learn a program is to learn the basics. I already took a class and want to take it further on my own to apply my skills for physics research. The class I took requires that no modules be imported, and I learned a bit more this way (like how to linspace without numpy). I was not aware of differences between libraries, though now that I know I will look into it (known unknowns vs unknown unknowns). I was under the impression that itertools was an import. The use of zip isn't alien to me, I tried unsuccessfully to use it in an operation instead of printing a result.

Comment: `itertools` *is* an import, but from the [standard library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/), which is shipped with most Python distributions (*"batteries included"*). `numpy` is a third-party module, which you need to *install* separately before importing.

Comment: That is not say imports are not useful; they are. But I want to explore them after the basics. As proof that I tried zip and did not find it helpful, here is one of my recent posts (mentioned in comment above) --> [proof](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41522534/how-do-i-combine-the-ith-element-of-2-lists-as-an-input-for-a-function)

Comment: In many cases, standard library modules *are* the basics!

Comment: I found your last few comments helpful and will investigate further. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> take i-th elements from lists A and B where (a,b) are the i-th elements of A and B
>
> want output = sum(a * var ** b) for index in len(A) if len(A) == len(B)

Is this what you're looking for? It will zip two lists of the same length together, calculating `f(a, b, i) = a[i] * var ** b[i]` for some constant `var` and for each `i` where `0 <= i < len(a)`. It then returns the sum.

```
def process(list_a, list_b, var):
    if len(list_a) != len(list_b):
        raise ValueError('Lists are not equal in length')

    def combine():
        for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b):
            yield a * var ** b

    return sum(combine())

print(process([5, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], 10))
```

**Output**

```
3300
```

This output is the result of `(1 * 10 ** 2) + (2 * 10 ** 2) + (3 * 10 ** 3)`.

**Edit**

The approach above decouples the combination logic - which is the focus of your question - from the summation logic. An alternative approach which is arguably more Pythonic (as per your requirements) and a lot shorter would be to use a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/), as suggested in the comments for this answer:

```
def process(list_a, list_b, var):
    if len(list_a) != len(list_b):
        raise ValueError('Lists are not equal in length')
    
    return sum(a * var ** b for a, b in zip(list_a, list_b))

print(process([1, 2, 3], [2, 2, 3], 10))
```

Essentially, the expression within `sum` acts as an anonymous replacement for the *generator function* `combine` that I defined in the previous approach.

Comment: It's a different formula than the one I was looking for but I should be able to apply the same principle to mine. Thank you! Edit: The formula is corrected, works like a charm.

Comment: @mikey A little sleepy and misread the formula. Is the formula in my edited post correct?

Comment: Yes, it is correct.

Comment: Can I ask what the downvote is for?

Comment: I upvoted your answer because the code works. Must have been someone else.

Comment: @mikey No worries, I was addressing that "someone else". :)

Comment: This is a perfect use-case for a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). simply `return sum(a*var**b for a,b in zip(list_a, list_b))`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I considered doing that (and I knew someone would eventually make this remark). In this case I wanted to completely decouple the "zip/combination" logic (focus of question) from the summation logic to make it clearer for OP (hopefully). If you post your approach, I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Tagc it was a suggesting for an addition to your question. I don't think there is any need for an additional answer.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Sure thing, done.

Comment: I appreciate seeing both methods. Thanks!